# Accessing derived class properties when implementing an interface method with abstract base class as parameter

Tags: c#

I tried hard to find an answer to this question, so if it is has been asked already, perhaps I'm wording it wrong. I have an abstract base class and a derived class.

```
abstract class Foo
{
   protected int property1
   protected int property2
// etc..
}
```

My dervied class contains some extra properties that are not found in the base class:

```
class Fum : Foo
{
   public int UniqueProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have an interface with a method that takes the abstract base class:

```
interface IDoSomethingWithFoos
{
   void DoSomethingWithFoo(Foo fooey);
}
```

A class that implements the interface

```
class FumLover : IDoSomethingWithFoos
{
   void DoSomethingWithFoo(Foo fooey)
   {
      // now in here i know i am going to be passed objects of Fum
      // and i want to access its unique properties

      fooey.UniqueProperty = 1;   // this doesn't work

      ((Fum)fooey).UniqueProperty = 1;   // this seems to work

      // as does..

      Fum refToFum = fooey as Fum;
      refToFum.UniqueProperty = 1;

   }
}
```

So my question is: am I going about this in the right way? Although this compiles, I don't have enough code in place to make sure yet it is actually going to work properly. And my other question is: is this bad design? Is there a better way?

*

To elaborate a little more, because the natural response is, if you are going to be passing Fum, then have the interface method take a Fum instead of a Foo.

But let's say in my FumLover class, the method DoSomethingWithFoo deals 95% with properties that ARE in the abstract bass class. And let's say I have another derived class called Fie, which has a couple of unique properties. Now let's say I have a FieLover class, and I want to implement DoSomethingWithFoo because 95% of what I'm going to do here could apply to all Foo, but again, there is a little bit that is unique to Fie.

What is the alternative? To have an interface for each one: IDoSomethingWithFums, IDoSomethingWithFies, etc.? It seems like I lose all the abstraction for just that 5% of difference.

Answer (score 4):

```
  // now in here i know i am going to be passed objects of Fum
  // and i want to access its unique properties
```

This is a clue that a design change might help. Your current interface says "I work on `Foo`s". If the implementation only works on `Fum`s, then you've got a mismatch in what you're saying and what you're doing. If you're really only expecting `Fum`s, then declare the parameter in the interface as a `Fum`.

If you don't want to do that, then using the `as` syntax is preferable, since then you don't throw an exception when someone thinks they can pass in a `Foo` (since hey, the interface *says* they can.)

The `as` code should look like this:

```
Fum fumObj = fooey as Fum;
if (fumObj != null)
    fumObj.UniqueProperty = 1;
```

**Update**:

Your suggestion of an interface for each derived class is actually preferable (since they say what they actually do,) but let's take a step back: what are you actually trying to accomplish here? If you want `IDoSomethingWithFoos` to take advantage of `Foo`'s place as a base class (albeit an abstract one,) then you need to ensure that calling `DoSomethingWithFoo` is meaningful for all `Foo`s. If not, then you've already lost, since even though you *claim* to be a FooLover, you really only love `Fum`s (or `Fie`s.)

One solution would be do declare an `abstract DoSomething()` method on `Foo` itself. Now, you could have a `List<Foo>`, and have code like this:

```
foreach (Foo foo in fooList)
    foo.DoSomething();
```

Now you're actually taking advantage of abstraction. You don't care what kind of `Foo`s those are: they all do something, possibly based on properties unique to only the derived class (no casting required.)

Comment: hmm, but correct me if i'm wrong, but since the interface takes an abstract class, it's always going to work on instances of derived classes (whether Fum or some other class). and what's the point of deriving a class from an abstract class if not to add some unique properties to it? it's almost like the interface says "i have to work with derived classes of this abstract base class but not with any of their unique aspects".

Comment: That's true, but usually when you have a method that accepts a less-derived version of a type, you expect it to be able to do it's job without accessing more derived properties. That's not always true (usually when you are exposing an API,) but it often is. My point is just that if your implementation *requires* info from the derived type, then declaring the parameter as such might be helpful. As I say above, if you don't care about that (which is perfectly fine) at least use the `as` option, so you don't go throwing unnecessary exceptions.

Comment: @suite16 That _is_ what the interface says (kind of).  Each derived class can BEHAVE differently, but once you have to know about a property or method that is unique to one implementation, you have lost the benefits of using the base class in the first place.

Comment: yeah i guess i get that. see my additional text for why it still doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: Note that in your new example, you're still not sharing any code (which is usually (though again, not always) the point of having the common base class.) Abstraction gains you the ability to ignore the details of the implementation that you are trying to "abstract away". But if you need to know the details when using the abstract class, you lose that. I'm going to update my answer to address this a bit more.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're doing is fine because Fum extends Foo you should be able to cast it in the way that you are.

Another approach would be to implement an IFoo interface and pass that into the method instead maybe.

Comment: Then what should happen when passed a `Foo` that is not a `Fum`? This code will throw an exception when the cast fails. Also, why declare it as `Foo` if you always want to use it as `Fum`?

Comment: What if you don't want to always pass `Fum`? What if you have other classes that derive from `Foo`? Your solution does not involve any forward thinking. I would have thought that given the fact that he knows about `class inheritance` he would know to check for `null` objects before trying to access them. Besides, it won't compile if you pass a class that does not extent `Foo`. Kindly remove the -1.

Comment: PS I wrote my answer while waiting for a train. hence there are no code snippets.